# Run Kettle transformation by java

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I created a java app (pilot) to run a kettle transformation. It's very simple, I have only the main method, that get a .ktr file and execute this.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            TransMeta transMeta = new TransMeta("C:\\user\\car.ktr");
            Trans trans = new Trans(transMeta); //create new transformation object
            trans.execute(null);
            trans.waitUntilFinished();
        } catch (KettleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get an exception.

```
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.5, build 1 from 2014-03-21_17-56-23 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Table output]
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.5, build 1 from 2014-03-21_17-56-23 by buildguy) : java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject.grabLoggingObjectInformation(LoggingObject.java:136)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject.<init>(LoggingObject.java:56)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingRegistry.registerLoggingSource(LoggingRegistry.java:70)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogChannel.<init>(LogChannel.java:74)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:191)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.init(TableOutput.java:598)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:65)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - Table output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014/12/23 08:24:54 - car - ERROR (version 5.0.5, build 1 from 2014-03-21_17-56-23 by buildguy) : Step [Table output.0] failed to initialize!
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
We failed to initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin!


    at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:1068)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.execute(Trans.java:578)
    at neoway.com.App.main(App.java:16)
```

It created this app with maven, and I have these dependencies.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-db</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
      <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.5</version>
   </dependency>
```

Anybody have any idea about the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It's better if you can attach Catalina.out and pentaho log files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add your database dependency in the pom.xml file. Since your transformation (the one which you are executing) is having a database connectivity, you need to import the corresponding jar to the eclipse workspace. Else eclipse will throw exceptions.

Check the [pentaho wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Running+kettle+transformation+using+Java) and also [this](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/java-and-pentaho-kettle-executing-a-kettle-file-using-java/) blog from me. I have used postgresql as a database connection. Try to modify the maven as per your database.

Hope it helps :)